# how to add a cell in a dynamic tableview section depending of a flag in objective-C

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm developing a dynamic tableview with two sections:
-Registered signatures
-Rejected signatures

all my values go on each section depending of a flag inside a dictionary:

```
[[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"idFirma"]
```

if it comes in 0 it means not registered signature, otherwise it means registered

but I'm not sure how to develop the section of printing in my method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

this is my development:

```
#pragma mark *** Common methods: Tableview delegate methods ***
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 0)   return @"not registered signatures";
    return @"Registered signatures";
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if ([self.userSignatures count] > 0){
        int firmasRegistradas = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.userSignatures count]; i++) {
            if (![[[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"idFirma"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
                firmasRegistradas += 1;
        }
        if (section == 0)   return [self.userSignatures count] - firmasRegistradas;
        if (section == 1)   return firmasRegistradas;
    }    
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel     *EntidadFirmante    = (UILabel *)   [cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel     *statusFirma        = (UILabel *)   [cell viewWithTag:3];

    if ([self.userSignatures count] > 0) {
        EntidadFirmante.text    = [[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"titFirmante"];
        statusFirma.text        = [[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"idDoc"];

        cell.accessoryType      = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        NSLog(@"idFirma: %@",[[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"idFirma"]);

        if (indexPath.section == 0 && [[[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"idFirma"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) return cell;
        else
        if (indexPath.section == 1 && ![[[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"idFirma"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) return cell;

    }
    else{
        EntidadFirmante.text    = @"There's no signatures";
        statusFirma.text        = @"without signatures";

        cell.accessoryType      = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

the key is here:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0 && [[[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"idFirma"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) return cell;
else
if (indexPath.section == 1 && ![[[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"idFirma"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) return cell;
```

if I have a list like this one

1. Registered
2. Registered
3. Unregistered
4. Registered

I expect something like this:

Registered Signatures:
1.
2.
4.

Unregistered signatures
3.

but so far I get something like this

Registered Signatures:
1.
2.
4.

Unregistered signatures
**1. (registered)**

if the unregisteded signature is the third one, it prints but the first one (registered)

any help I'll appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sections change it resets indexPath.  You are correctly identifying the number of rows but since both your registered and unregistered data are in the same array it is displaying the data at index 1 in the unregistered section. Thats why for a section with a row count of 1 it displays the data at index 1 of your array.

You could fix this a number of ways.  You could separate your data into a registered array and into an unregistered array.  Or you can identify the correct index of the unregistered data and pass that to the objectAtIndexPath method.

Also, IMHO your code would be a lot cleaner if you configured your cell in the method:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

}

instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: do you have an example of this, I also added a global counter: indexArraySignatures replacing it instead indexpath.row on [self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:indexArraySignatures] but stills the same :/

Comment: No thats not it, you are just recreating the same problem a different way.  You need logic that does something like this `if isEqualToString:@"unregistered" { NSMutableArray *unregisteredArray = [NSMutableArray addObject:indexPath.row];}`  This will sort out the unregistered data.  Then loop through the data something like `[self.userSignitures objectAtIndex:[unregisteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]` when you are displaying the unregistered section.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I make it work thanks to WeekendCodeWarrior suggestions, now this is my code:

```
#pragma mark *** UITableviewDelegate ***
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //Devuelve el título que tendrá cada sección
    if (section == 0)   return @"not registered signatures";
    return @"Registered signatures";
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    registeredSignatures    = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    unregisteredSignatures  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.userSignatures count]; i++) {
        if ([[[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"idFirma"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
            [unregisteredSignatures addObject:[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:i]];
        else
        if (![[[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"idFirma"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
                [registeredSignatures addObject:[self.userSignatures objectAtIndex:i]];
    }


    if (section == 0)   return [unregisteredSignatures count];
    if (section == 1)   return [registeredSignatures count];
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel     *EntidadFirmante    = (UILabel *)   [cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel     *statusFirma        = (UILabel *)   [cell viewWithTag:3];

    if ([self.userSignatures count] > 0) {
        cell.accessoryType      = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            EntidadFirmante.text    = [[unregisteredSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"titFirmante"];
            statusFirma.text        = [[unregisteredSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"idDoc"];    
        }

        else
            if (indexPath.section == 1) {
                EntidadFirmante.text    = [[registeredSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"titFirmante"];
                statusFirma.text        = [[registeredSignatures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"idDoc"];
            }
    }
    else{
        EntidadFirmante.text    = @"There's no signatures";
        statusFirma.text        = @"without signatures";

        cell.accessoryType      = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

thanks for the support!!!